# Are pibase extensions still working in TYPO3 8?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-8.x

I have to migrate TYPO3 6.2 websites to 8.7. Some websites use custom pibase extensions, do I need to redevelop them with Extbase ?

Comment: You dont need, they should still work. Class tslib_pibase has changed to  \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Plugin\AbstractPlugin since TYPO3 v6 and is still available

Comment: There exists the extension migration_core which helps to do most class replacements automatically for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you don't need to redevelop these extensions, but you might need to change the call to core functions.
In 6.2 you still could use the old class names like `t3lib`.
These class names are available only with compatibility layer (together with a lot of delay).

For the future you need to use namespaces (and the correct new classes). You also should use namespaces for your own classes.

Depending on your used functions you might need to replace some calls with the newer functions as some functions got deprecated meanwhile.

Answer (score 17):

**delete reason**: while this answer was upvoted a lot, it is actually off-topic for the question. Because it is the highest votest answer (June 6, 2022) it drowns out other answers. That is why I decided to delete it.

## Resources

I found the following ressources helpful for porting:

### Update to 6.2+

- [ClassAliasMap.php](https://git.typo3.org/Packages/TYPO3.CMS.git/blob/refs/heads/TYPO3_6-2:/typo3/sysext/core/Migrations/Code/ClassAliasMap.php) (mapping of old to new classes)

### Update to 7+

- Wiki: [TYPO3 7 migration guide](https://wiki.typo3.org/TYPO3_7.6_Extension_Migration_Guide)
- Official ["Changelog" for 7](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog-7.html) (look at "Breaking Changes" for everything that you **must** replace, look at "Deprecations" for everything that is **recommended** to replace)

### Update to 8+

- Official ["Changelog" for 8](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog-8.html)

### Update to 9+

- Official ["Changelog" for 9](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog-9.html)
- [Migrating from TYPO3_DB](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/Migration/Index.html) in "TYPO3 Explained" for converting old database functions to QueryBuilder. You can convert to QueryBuilder or Extbase [Query](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/6-Persistence/3-implement-individual-database-queries.html). ($GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB'] is no longer available since 9, except if you use the extension typo3db_legacy!)

Also:

- Cleaning up TCA: [Andreas Fernandez: Cleaning the hood](https://www.scripting-base.de/blog/cleaning-the-hood-tca.html)
- [Daniel Goerz (usetypo3): Upgrading Projects](https://usetypo3.com/upgrading-projects.html)

## In general

The changes, that you need to make, may be trivial. In other cases, significant.

All things considered, I would *usually* recommend a rewrite using Extbase or Doctrine DBAL (QueryBuilder) and Fluid, Namespaces, TYPO3 9 API (maybe even TYPO3 10 if possible). Your extension will (probably) be better maintainable in the long run.

### Tip

- If you migrate to TYPO3 9 or above, use the [extension scanner](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/ExtensionScanner/Index.html) to detect code that will most likely cause problems. It is incredibly helpful for cleaning up legacy code. (You can also scan uninstalled extensions in a TYPO3 9 installation).
- Alternatively, the use of [rector](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector) is often used to automatically make changes to PHP in extensions. Rules are available for TYPO3 via [sabbelasichon/typo3-rector](https://github.com/sabbelasichon/typo3-rector)

### Changes

You may need to change one or more of the following (and **this is not a complete list**!):

#### Replace old with new classes

In most cases, I needed to replace  a subset of:

- Tx_Extbase_Utility_Extension :   \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility
- t3lib_extMgm :
  \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility
- t3lib_div :
  \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility
- tslib_cObj :
  \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer
- t3lib_utility_VersionNumber :
  \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\VersionNumberUtility
- t3lib_BEfunc :
  \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Utility\BackendUtility
- t3lib_TCEmain :
  \TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler
- t3lib_parsehtml_proc :
  \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Html\RteHtmlParser

See [ClassAliasMap.php](https://git.typo3.org/Packages/TYPO3.CMS.git/blob/refs/heads/TYPO3_6-2:/typo3/sysext/core/Migrations/Code/ClassAliasMap.php) for a complete list.

#### TCA

- Use $GLOBALS['TCA'] instead of $TCA
- Move override TCA to Configuration/TCA/Overrides, see [Breaking Change #78384](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.5/Breaking-78384-FrontendIgnoresTCAInExtTables.html), TCA for your own model to Configuration/TCA. ext_tables.php will eventually be deprecated.
- [Third Parameter in addTCAColums is deprecated](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/54899)

See "[Andreas Fernandez: Cleaning the hood](https://www.scripting-base.de/blog/cleaning-the-hood-tca.html)" for a very nice description of cleaning up the TCA with real examples.

#### PageRenderer

- replace $this->getPageRenderer with `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\PageRenderer::class);`

#### page.includeJSlibs

"page.includeJSlibs is marked for deprecation and will be removed in TYPO3 CMS 8. Please use page.includeJSLibs (with an uppercase L) instead"

Answer (score 10):

All previous answers have been correct but some words from a TYPO3 core team member: There are no plans to drop the support of "pibase" in the core. It is absolutely ok to use that API even though it does not provide much help to developers.

---

However I recommend to use at least fluid standalone to be able to create nice templates without all those `###` stuff.

Comment: Thanks, I will follow your recommendation.

Comment: Hi @Georg Ringer, thank you for your clear statement. As your statement is now 1.5 years old, I'd like to ask, are pibased plugins still not deprecated? - And do you know why no one here is recommending the compatibility plugins for pibase extensions?

Comment: The API is still not deprecated. The compatibility plugins are not recommended because it just moves the technical debts to the future and it will hit you later. Those extensions are also not maintained

Comment: @GeorgRinger That's maybe a stupid question but: When I am using a pibase extension that is having this ### stuff, can I mix it with Fluid and using the ### markers for the output?

Comment: you could of course use a fluid standalone view and use that result

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to redevelop these extensions.

Just you need to change some TYPO3 core function like `t3lib_div` `t3lib_BEfunc` `t3lib_parsehtml` `t3lib_extMgm` and more..

Please see complete example here : [See more details](https://github.com/AOEpeople/TYPO3-Static-Pub/pull/1/files)